# Installed 14.04 LTS dual boot with Win 8.1, now network not detected by either

Tags: wireless, networking, dual-boot

Had to turn off secure boot and install Ubuntu in Legacy mode. I can boot to windows with boot option "OS Boot Manager", boot to Ubuntu using "Notebook Hard Disk" option in "Boot Optons" menu.

First Ubuntu saw the network, but couldn't connect. Then in same session, all wireless networks disappeared, I.e. Could not be detected.

When I use "network Hard Drive" option I get grub, and if I choose windows, I get a boot error from windows and a frozen machine.

I suspect I screwed up some boot spec or drivers associated with wi-fi. Wired Ethernet seems to work ok in either OS.

I'm on an HP Pavilion with an AMD Processor.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: It is a new machine, like 6 months old. It's hard to find any recognizable model no. Is my best option to restore windows from backup partition, delete other partition, then re-install Ubuntu, i.e. Start from scratch? I don't even need to backup any data. But there are a lot of different install approaches. Perhaps I should wait a month or two.

Comment: Try booting from a LiveUSB. If the wireless network doesn't work there either the problem is in hardware or bios.

Comment: Which exact HP do you have? Also look for Ubuntu installation guides for that model

Answer (score 0):

All PCs that are sold with Windows 8/8.1 usually are installed under EFI (UEFI) instead of the traditional BIOS. I believe (not completely sure) that Windows 8 onwards use GPT (GUID Partition Table) instead of MBR (Master Boot Record). With this I assume you had to setup 'biosgrub' partitions and you have to manually boot into the Ubuntu biosgrub partition or the Windows Boot Manager. I would check your PC maker and see if they have an update to your BIOS, this might allow you to install both under EFI and use GPT instead so you don't have to have all these boot managers and biosgrub partitions. As for the Wi-Fi plug it into a wired connection and go to additional drivers and see if anything is available.

Comment: Thanks. Many new wifi drivers at HP. Seems to have fixed both OS's problems. Boot still awkward, bit it works.